# Why can't I use slideUp() for two different events for the same element?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, delay, slideup

I have this session message:

```
<div class="alert alert-success session-message text-center">
    Hi
    <a href="#" class="pull-right close-message">&times;</a>
</div>
```

And I have this jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.close-message').click(function(){
        $('.session-message').slideUp();
    });
    $('.session-message').delay(2000).slideUp();
});
```

As this code stands, when I click the <kbd>×</kbd> button, the message does not `slideUp`.  However, if I comment out the delay part, clicking on the <kbd>×</kbd> does what I want it to do:

```
$(function(){
    $('.close-message').click(function(){
        $('.session-message').slideUp();
    });
    // $('.session-message').delay(2000).slideUp();
});
```

Furthermore, if I change the click animation from `slideUp()` to anything else, like `fadeOut()`, it still doesn't work.  But if I change it to something like `hide()`, it does work.

What am I doing wrong?  What can I do so that I can click to `slideUp()` the message or just wait for it to `slideUp()` after 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) because you have registered animation queue for the element on *DOM ready*.

```
$(function(){
   $('.close-message').click(function(){
        // without the .stop(), it will wait until the first animation in queue is done
        $('.session-message').stop().slideUp();
   });

   // registered animation queue for the element on DOM ready:
   $('.session-message').delay(2000).slideUp();
});
```

```js
$('.close-message').click(function(){
  $('.session-message').stop().slideUp();
});

$('.session-message').delay(2000).slideUp();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success session-message text-center">
    Hi
    <a href="#" class="pull-right close-message">&times;</a>
</div>
```

---

> (...) But if I change it to something like `hide()`, it does work

Because `.hide()` is not an animation and therefore it's not in the animations queue.